# Class Object Not Recognized

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with a class object not being recognized (error 91, object reference not set). Here's the code:

```
---Main (Standard Module)
Option Explicit
Public wbCode As Workbook

Public Sub MainSub()
Dim str As String
Dim tables As New CTables
Call SetExcelObjects
str = tables.shExclusions.Cells(20, 1) ---this produces error 91
End Sub

Public Sub SetExcelObjects()
Dim tables As New CTables
Dim str As String
Set wbCode = ThisWorkbook
Set tables.shExclusions = wbCode.Worksheets("Exclusions")
str = tables.shExclusions.Cells(20, 1) ---this line executes okay
End Sub


---CTables (Class Module)
Option Explicit
Public shExclusions As Worksheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
---Main (Standard Module) 
Option Explicit 
Public wbCode As Workbook 

Public Sub MainSub() 
Dim str As String 
Dim tables As New CTables 
Call SetExcelObjects(tables)
str = tables.shExclusions.Cells(20, 1) ---this produces error 91 
End Sub 

Public Sub SetExcelObjects(tables as CTables) 
Dim str As String 
Set wbCode = ThisWorkbook 
Set tables.shExclusions = wbCode.Worksheets("Exclusions") 
str = tables.shExclusions.Cells(20, 1) ---this line executes okay 
End Sub 


---CTables (Class Module) 
Option Explicit 
Public shExclusions As Worksheet
```

Comment: +1, Though because it was difficult for me to tell what change you suggested, I am explaining for future readers. The issue is that the object `tables` was not being set within the scope of Main. By passing the object reference to `SetExcelObjects`, `SetExcelObjects` is able to define `tables` to make it useable. An alternate solution would have been to make tables a private variable for the whole module.